Citing a warranty deed: which date to use?
A 1900 warranty deed contains the date it was drafted and the date it was filed. I find conflicting information about which date to use in my citation.

Evidence Explained, in the 2012 post titled Clarification on SS-5 citations, responds to a date conflict in the reply to Kingrat, "If we are citing a deed, the relevant date would be the date the deed was drafted."
St Louis Genealogical Society, in 2016 Citations - Land Records, specifically notes in the section on Court Records to use the date filed.
Evidence Explained, 3rd edition, simply shows a date and has no discussion. When I visit the example, the document is from the 1800s and was drafted & filed the same day.

Some rural deeds are filed months after drafting, and in the meanwhile, the new owner might have sold the parcel to yet another party. It was the new owner's parcel to sell, wasn't it?
Another consideration: Deed books are organized by date filed.
Which date goes in the citation: date drafted or date filed?

In the introduction to Evidence Explained 3rd edition, Elizabeth Shown Mills says:

We identify our sources—and their strengths and weaknesses—so we can reach the most reliable conclusion.

Think about this as you also consider the principle of "cite what you used". You aren't looking at the original warranty deed. You are looking at the copy which is in the deed book. You need to have that information in order to locate the deed again. You also need to know the date the warranty deed was drafted, and the interval between draft and filing, to evaluate it properly.  Wouldn't it be better to have both dates in the citation?
Here's a thought experiment.  Suppose some county deed records from a Confederate state got taken away by Union soldiers and were later returned to an archive in the state where they belong. If people had taken in their deeds and had them re-recorded in the interval, there might be multiple deed book copies of the same warranty deed. To distinguish which copy you saw, you would need to record the date the deed was filed.  If you had copies of the same warranty deed from two different deed books, you would need to know the interval between the date of the draft and the copy in the copybook.
Whatever you decide to put in the citation itself, I would record both dates in my research notes simply to make it clear exactly what I looked at and how I found it.
Remember too that if you are preparing a citation for a published article, the journal may have a style sheet and preferences of its own.

I photocopied the deed book 30 years ago before I began learning to cite; which I am still learning. Based on your suggestions, I have amended my citation:
Dodge County, Nebraska, Deed Book 32 [1905-1906]: 432, George Johnson a widower of Dodge County to Frank J. Uher of Dodge Nebr., drafted 2 September 1905, filed 27 February 1906; Office of the Register of Deeds, Fremont.

Since both have relevance, why not cite both? That's what I'd do - but if you are supposed to be following a particular standard, you should do what that says.
